# A classe Model padrão MVC no PHP

Tags: php, mvc

Estou estudando MVC, criei a classe Model abstrata para servir de "molde" para as demais que poderão herdá-la. Gostaria de uma avaliação do código como, pontos positivos e negativos, qual a melhor forma de melhorá-lo, etc.

```
abstract class Model {

private $sql;

protected function setSql($sql_query) {

    return isset($sql_query) ? $this -> sql = $sql_query : false;
}

public function getAll() {

    $query = $this -> db -> prepare($this -> sql);
    try {
        $query -> execute();
        return $query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e -> getMessage());
    }
}

public function getById($id) {

    $query = $this -> db -> prepare($this -> sql);
    $query -> bindValue(1, $id);

    try {
        $query -> execute();
        return $query -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e -> getMessage());
    }
}

public function getBySearch($search_term) {

    $query = $this -> db -> prepare($this -> sql);
    $query -> bindValue(1, $search_term);

    try {
        $query -> execute();
        return $query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e -> getMessage());

    }

}

public function deleteById($id) {/*será implementada*/}
public function updateById($id) {/*será implementada*/}
public function insert() {/*será implementada*/ }
```

}

E esta seria a chamada numa classe filha:

```
public function getUserById($id) {

    $this -> setSql("SELECT * FROM XXX WHERE id = ?");
    return $this -> getById($id);
```

Comment: Esta pergunta está sendo discutida do Meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1510/devemos-aceitar-pedidos-de-melhoramento-de-c%C3%B3digo

Comment: Recomendo utilizar o Doctrine. É uma excelente ferramenta de abstração e mapeamento dos relacionamentos. Dê uma conferida na [documentação](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/)

Answer (score 3):

### Pontos Positivos

- A sua classe Model está lembrando muito as classes DAO (Data Access Object), o que separa a responsabilidade de resgatar os objetos (resultados) da responsabilidade de representar o objeto.

### Pontos Negativos

- Seria legal abstrair o resultado (cada linha do banco de dados) ao invés de retornar um array associativo
- Você está usando SQL, se você criar um Objeto para Representar o critério da consulta você vai ter uma independência de banco de dados SQL e NoSQL.

### Exemplo

Acredito que tudo deveria ser abstraido, para tornar o desenvolvimento mais natural, por exemplo ao invés de:

```
echo $model['first_name'].' '.$model['last_name']
```

você poderia digitar

```
echo $model->full_name;
```

A função iria cuidar de juntar transformar os dados em informações mais úteis.

A mesma coisa se aplica para a consulta, ao invés de

```
$person = $personModel->getBySearch("SELECT * FROM person WHERE name = 'Joe'");
```

Você poderia usar

```
$person = Person::$objects->filter(array('name'=>'Joe'))->first();
```

Ou ainda

```
$person = Person::$objects->byName('Joe')->first();
```

No rails, por exemplo, ele cria métodos para filtrar cada atributo (automaticamente)

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas, sou um pouco novo nisso, eu entendi e não entendi ao mesmo tempo rs, quais padrões de projeto que eu deveria estudar?